# Using HashMap with custom key

Tags: java, dictionary

Quick Question: If I want to use `HashMap` with a custom class as the key, **must** I override the `hashCode` function? How will it work if I do not override that function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you don't have to override the hashCode method as long as equal objects have the same hashCode.

So, if you use the default behaviour defined by Object, where equals only returns true only for the same instance, then you don't have to override the hashCode method.

But if you don't override the equals and the hashCode methods, it means you have to make sure you're always using the same key instance.

E.g.:

```
MyKey key1_1 = new MyKey("key1");

myMap.put(key1_1,someValue); // OK

someValue = myMap.get(key1_1); // returns the correct value, since the same key instance has been used;

MyKey key1_2  = new MaKey("key1"); // different key instance

someValue = myMap.get(key1_2); // returns null, because key1_2 has a different hashCode than key1_1 and key1_1.equals(key1_2) == false
```

In practice you often have only one instance of the key, so technically you don't have to override the equals and hashCode methods.

But it's best practice to override the equals and hashCode methods for classes used as keys anyway, because sometime later you or another developer might forget that the same instance has to be used, which can lead to hard to track issues.

And note: even if you override the equals and hashCode methods, you must make sure you don't change the key object in a way that would change the result of the equals or the hashCode methods, otherwise the map won't find your value anymore. That's why it's recommended to use immutable objects as keys if possible.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't override hashCode AND equals you will get the default behaviour which is that each object is different, regardless of its contents.

Comment: Unless he's extending something that has a hashCode that works for him

Answer (score 4):

The only time you don't have to override the `hashCode()` function is when you also don't override `equals`, so you use the default `Object.equals` definition of reference equality.  This may or may not be what you want -- in particular, different objects will *not* be considered equal even if they have the same field values.

If you override `equals` but not `hashCode`, `HashMap` behavior will be undefined (read: it won't make any sense at all, and will be totally corrupted).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the object class you are using as a key. If it's a custom class like you propose, and it doesn't extend anything (i.e. it extends `Object`) then the hashCode function will be that of `Object`, and that will consider memory references, making two objects that look the same to you hash to different codes.

So yes, unless you are extending a class with a `hashCode()` function you know works for you, you need to implement your own. Also make sure to implement `equals()`: some classes like `ArrayList` will only use equals while others like HashMap will check on both `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Just checked the HashMap.put() to be sure, and I indeed had it wrong. Thanks! I fixed the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Without checking the implementation details, you can see that on an abstract level it must be so due to the inavoidability of hash collisions. Any two objects colliding on a hashcode would end up the same if `equals` was not considered.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also that if your key is not immutable you may have problems. If you put an entry with a mutable key in the map an you change later the key in a way that it affects hashcode and equals you may lose your entry in the map,as you won't be able to retrieve it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods from the Object class. The default implementation of the `equals()` and `hashcode()`, which are inherited from the `java.lang.Object` uses an object instance’s memory location (e.g. `MyObject@6c60f2ea`). This can cause problems when two instances of the an objects have the same properties but the inherited `equals()` will return `false` because it uses the `memory location`, which is different for the two instances.

Also the `toString()` method can be overridden to provide a proper string representation of your object.

**primary considerations when implementing a user defined key**

1. If a class overrides `equals()`, it must override `hashCode()`.
2. If 2 objects are equal, then their `hashCode` values must be equal as well.
3. If a field is not used in `equals()`, then it must not be used in `hashCode()`.
4. If it is accessed often, `hashCode()` is a candidate for caching to enhance performance.