# Do I need to create my own hash and equal methods?

Tags: java, hash, key

```
class EventManager{
    public String unique_ID;
    public List<Object> infoList;

    public EventManager(String ID, List<Object> infoList){
        this.unique_ID = ID;
        this.infoList = infoList;
    }
}
```

If this class is used a map key, do I need to implement my own hashcode and equal() methods?

If it's needed, just hash the unique_ID is enough? Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: See the first answer to [this question][1], which the above question duplicates.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281166/using-hashmap-with-custom-key

Answer (score 1):

if you don't define your own hashcode, I believe it will use the address of the object. So if you create two instances with the same id, they won't hash to the same bucket. You probably want to use id for equality. As a side note, make sure not use the List in your equality or hashing unless you can guarantee immutablity.

[How default .equals and .hashCode will work for my classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178997/how-default-equals-and-hashcode-will-work-for-my-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you want to override the values of `hashCode` and equals to give them a different `behaviour`.

If not, you can just use the defaults, and each different object will have a different `hashCode`, in a way more or less guaranteed by the JVM.

You only need to override `equals`, for instance, if you wanted to be able to say that two objects are the same if certain conditions meet (for instance, just the `unique_ID` being the same).

If you *do* override `equals`, then you *must* override `hashCode`, to respect the Object contract:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).
>
> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: For any class, if I don't customize the hash code and equal, any two instances will always be treated as differently, because their addresses are always different. Right?

Comment: Yes, right. If both instances are different, they will have a different hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that if you don't override equals then two instances will only be equal if they are, in fact, the SAME instance (ie, equal addresses).  If you want instances containing equal fields to be treated as equal you need to implement your own version.

If you override equal then you must override hashcode as well, to assure that two equal instances return identical hashcodes.  Failure to do this will cause HashMap, et al, to fail.

Note that it's perfectly legal (though stupid) for hashcode to always return 6 or some other fixed value.  What it **must not** do is return two different hashcode values for equal instances.